# plt.subplots() opens multiple windows

Tags: matplotlib

I am using the below code to produce 3 charts in the same figure, but it is annoyingly opening up 3 windows. I am following the steps given in the link 
http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/recipes.htm. Somebody please help me. I want to get all the charts in a single window.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = [1,2,3]
value = {}
value['x'] = [1,2,3]
value['y'] = [1,4,9]
value['z'] = [1,8,27]
for k, dimension in enumerate(['x', 'y', 'z']):
    fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True,sharey=True)
    axs[k].plot(time, value[dimension])

plt.show()
```

Update: Solved
The below version works fine. The subplots was inside the for loop.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
time = [1,2,3]
value = {}
value['x'] = [1,2,3]
value['y'] = [1,4,9]
value['z'] = [1,8,27]
fig, axs = plt.subplots(3, 1, sharex=True,sharey=True)
for k, dimension in enumerate(['x', 'y', 'z']):
    axs[k].plot(time, value[dimension])

plt.show()
```

Comment: If you answer your own question before anyone else, feel free to post it below as an answer (self-answers are fine), that way you can actually mark it answered.